# Why my nested form don't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have nested form for my GameDate model and RefereeStat model. They are connected with has_many association. Without nesting, both models are saving. But in nested form, my app won't save them. I suspect that the problem is in form, probably in association with showcase controller, but I can't figure it out.

This is output from console:

> Started POST "/game_dates" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-24 20:38:07 +0100
>   Processing by GameDatesController#create as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"umpbTCZekqIU/g6uVdlde9fSubutgLk0Qrbb0e5GCdn3qj4/C0tmlxl/akxaM1Vmr6v8dNB8b88ATpRN8v1U2g==",
>   "game_date"=>{"date(1i)"=>"2016", "date(2i)"=>"3", "date(3i)"=>"24",
>   "referee_stats_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"games_count"=>"3",
>   "showcase_id"=>"10"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Game date"}   User Load
>   (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER
>   BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]    (0.4ms)  BEGIN    (0.3ms) 
>   ROLLBACK   Showcase Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "showcases".* FROM
>   "showcases"   Rendered game_dates/_form.html.haml (22.4ms)   Rendered
>   game_dates/new.html.haml within layouts/application (23.9ms)
>   Rendered layouts/_header.html.haml (0.7ms)   Rendered
>   shared/_flash.html.haml (0.2ms) Completed 200 OK in 148ms (Views:
>   138.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)

This is GameDate model:

```
class GameDate < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :date, presence: true

  has_many :referee_stats
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :referee_stats, :reject_if => :all_blank
end
```

Game date controller:

```
class GameDatesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :user_is_admin

  def new
    @game_date = GameDate.new
    @game_date.referee_stats.build
  end

  def create
    @game_date = GameDate.new(game_date_params)
    if @game_date.save
      redirect_to showcases_path
      flash[:success] = "Game date created"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @game_date = GameDate.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @game_date = GameDate.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to root_url
    flash[:success] = "Game date deleted"
  end


  private

  def game_date_params
    params.require(:game_date).permit(:date, referee_stats_attributes: [ :games_count, :showcase_id ])
  end

  def user_is_admin
    unless current_user.admin?
      flash[:error] = "You don't have permission to perform this action!"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
end
```

Referee stat model:

```
class RefereeStat < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :games_count,  presence: true, numericality: {
                           only_integer: true,
                           greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }

  validates :showcase_id,  presence: true
  validates :game_date_id, presence: true

  belongs_to :showcase
  belongs_to :game_date

end
```

Form:

```
.container
  .row
    .col-md-6.col-md-offset-3
      = simple_form_for @game_date do |f|
        = f.error_notification
        %h2.text-center Game date
        = f.input :date
        = f.simple_fields_for :referee_stats do |r|
          %h3.text-center Referee statistics
          = r.input :games_count
          = r.association :showcase, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, include_blank: false
        = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm"
```

Comment: replace `  f.simple_fields_for :referee_stats do |r|` with `  f.simple_fields_for @game_date.referee_stats do |r|` It should work.

Comment: OR just removing` @game_date.referee_stats.build` in controller will also resolve this situation.

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli when I've removed '@game_date.referee_stats.build' fields for referee_stats deasapear. When I change my form with your first advise, I've recived this error "undefined method `has_attribute?' for #<RefereeStat::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f7d4051e0b8>"

Comment: Your code looks fine to me and is working for me same way. Is your code on git or you can share so that i can try to debug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into your git code and found solution :

> You are not passing game_date_id from the game_date new form and it
>   failing at game_date_id presence validation and not allowing you to
>   save record so, its better to use association name validation to
>   ensure presence of record.

Actually, presence validator for foreign key don’t care about record existence. It means that you are able to pass game_date_id from form.

Change the following line in referee_stat.rb & it will work for you :

```
validates :game_date_id, presence: true
   replace with
validate :game_date
    OR
validates :game_date, presence: true, if: -> {game_date_id.present?}
```

> Validating foreign key and the association itself are explained at
>   this [blog](http://railsguides.net/belongs-to-and-presence-validation-rule1/).

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your `referee_stats_attributes` are passed like such:

```
"referee_stats_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"games_count"=>"3", "showcase_id"=>"10"}}
```

But they should be passed like this:

```
"referee_stats_attributes"=>[{"games_count"=>"3", "showcase_id"=>"10"}]
```

The id `"0"` is not needed; Rails magic will auto-create this for you. You only need to pass an id if you're updating, and even then, it should be passed like so:

```
"referee_stats_attributes"=>[{"id" => 1, "games_count"=>"3", "showcase_id"=>"10"}]
```

I have not used `simple_form_for` so can't comment on the syntax, because it looks OK... but check the HTML output, your `<input>` for the child objects should look like this:

```
<input name="referee_stats[][games_count]" ... />
<input name="referee_stats[][showcase_id]" ... />
```